# Python looping sql results not changing when updated

Tags: python, sql, loops

When I run the below code, it continues to return the same information even if I change the data saved in the database or insert another row into the database.  When I restart the script it pulls the new updated information. I would like the program to pull the most up to date data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
def readLastTemp():
    cur = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT Temperature FROM Temperatures ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1" 
    cur.execute(sql) 
    results = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    for row in results:
        Temperature = row[0]
        return Temperature

while True:
    print(readLastTemp())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: @Mox, OP is calling the function in a loop.

Comment: may I ask whats the database being used here?

Comment: On a side note, why are you returning from a loop?

Comment: it seems that the sql will return a max of 1 row.

Comment: In addition, how are u updating the DB? via commandline or via another script? if it is the latter, u may want to consider flushing/committing the change. whatever change that you thought is there could be stored in page cache rather than physical storage.

Comment: @Mox I am updating a MariaDB in the phpmyadmin view